# Why is my home server getting assigned 2 IP addresses from the router?

Tags: networking

This is a table from my router's admin WebUI

```
Device name     MAC address         IP address          Speed(Mbps)     Connected to
konsoletta      00:16:CB:B0:8F:CC   192.168.0.101/24    1000            Ethernet 3
Nieznane        00:16:CB:B0:8F:CC   192.168.0.26/24     1000            Ethernet 3
... more ...
```

I've manually assigned 192.168.0.101 to my home server (Ubuntu 18.04 running on an old Mac Mini), but there's always this second IP assigned to my machine and I don't know where it's coming from. It's main purpose is running Plex, Samba and some cron jobs.
This is an `ip addr` output:

```
➜  ~ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:cb:b0:8f:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.101/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:cbff:feb0:8fcc/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1f:f3:d9:2d:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:58:97:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.123.1/24 brd 192.168.123.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:58:97:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Nothing about this *other* address (`192.168.0.26`).

So what's going on here?

Comment: Does this computer have two network adapters connected to the same network?

Comment: Which "other" address do you mean exactly? The `inet6 fe80::...` address is a link-local IPv6 (not IPv4) address that's automatically assigned to all IPv6 capable interfaces by the computer itself (not by the router). Your virtual bridge `virbr0` (whatever it is for) is in a different subnet. So I don't see any second address assigned by the router.

Comment: @harrymc There's only one cable going from computer to router, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @dirkt 192.168.0.26! Obviously (I think). That's the point, it ain't there but the router says otherwise.

Comment: The router might have a long memory. Try to turn all off, boot router, followed by the computer.

Comment: You mean "in your routers UI" and not "the PC is getting assigned two addresses"? That's just a quirk of the router software. Ingore that, or reboot, or delete manually, ...